# Why is the date not saving to my database?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a comments object that is mapped to a mysql database. Comments consists of the following fields: (comment_id, commentText, commentdate). comment_id is an autogenerated integer, while comment text is taken from input from a JSF page. When I call the addComment method, commentText is populated in the database as expected, however commentdate remains null, despite being set in the method (by creating a string of the return value of calculateCurrentDateTime method). The code is shown below. If anyone can tell me what the problem is it is much appreciated.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class CommentBean {

private Comment comment;
private static EntityManagerFactory factory;
private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "NeedABuilderUnit";
private List<BusinessAccount> businessAccount;
private List<Comment> listOfComments;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    comment = new Comment();
}

public String addComment(int contractorId) {
    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();   
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Query myQuery = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM BusinessAccount u WHERE u.id=:id");
        myQuery.setParameter("id", contractorId);

        List<BusinessAccount> accounts=myQuery.getResultList();
        BusinessAccount account =accounts.get(0);

        String date=calculateCurrentDateTime();
        comment.setCommentdate(date);


        comment.setBusinessAccount(account); //managing both sides

        account.getComments().add(comment); //managing both sides
        em.persist(comment);

        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        comment.setCommentText(null);

        return "success";
    }


public String calculateCurrentDateTime() {


       DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");     
       //get current date time with Calendar()
       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       String currentDate=dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());

return currentDate;

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "comments")
public class Comment {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int comment_id;

@Column(name = "comment_text")
private String commentText;

@Column(name = "date")
private String commentdate;



@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "contractor_id", referencedColumnName="id") })
private BusinessAccount businessAccount;

public BusinessAccount getBusinessAccount() {
    if (businessAccount == null) {
        businessAccount = new BusinessAccount();
    }
    return businessAccount;
}

public void setBusinessAccount(BusinessAccount businessAccount) {
    this.businessAccount = businessAccount;
}

public int getComment_id() {
    return comment_id;
}

public void setComment_id(int comment_id) {
    this.comment_id = comment_id;
}

public String getCommentText() {
    return commentText;
}

public void setCommentText(String commentText) {
    this.commentText = commentText;
}

public String getCommentdate() {
    return commentdate;
}

public void setCommentdate(String commentdate) {
    this.commentdate = commentdate;
}
```

}

Comment: you don't show your `INSERT` query, so there's no way to tell. probably you're using an invalid date format, instead of the mysql required `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. If that date you're building in `calculateCurrentDateTime()` is what you're sending to mysql, then no wonder. It's not a valid mysql time string format. Plus, if you just need to insert the current date/time, do it in mysql `insert datefield VALUES (now())`. No need for all that string generation/mangling.

Comment: insert to the database is done with persist above.

Comment: What is the data type of the date column in table? A `varchar`?

Comment: @Ravinder yes it's a varchar(45) so is long enough to hold the string.

Answer (score 0):

Make date format as

`Y-m-d H:i:s`, this is the format for mysql

```
SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. I'm not getting an error just a blank field in the database. The value I'm passing at the moment is a string so the format shouldn't matter, and the method for date/time returns the correct string that I want to insert to the database. Thanks

Comment: what is the data type u have for date field. Also remember the date should be treated as string while adding to mysql else it will not get added. If possible please post the insert query after values are passed this could tell more about it.

Comment: I don't use an insert query. This is done with em.persist above where comment, the instance of the Comment object is persisted to the database. The field in the database is a varchar. Thanks

Comment: hmm interesting.. u have varchar and it should add regardless of any date format. Are u sure the method calculateCurrentDateTime is returning something and setting it to the object member.

Comment: I ran the debugger and the date is returning fine as a string but for some reason when I set it to the comment object ( comment.setCommentdate(date);) it has no effect. Value in the db is null.

Comment: Even if I just try to set a regular string it has no efeect-just not being added to the database.

Answer (score 0):

why cant u change the the 
@Column(name = "date")
private String commentdate;

to

@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTimeAsString")
@NotNull
private LocalDateTime commentDate;

so that you can set the currentDate as,

commentDate = LocalDateTime.now();

which will solve the problem and there is no need to call the calculateCurrentDateTime() method as LocalDateTime.now() will return the current date....